# Detect if a resource from an external domain loads at the users end

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have absolutely no idea if its even possible but its something I'd like to experiment with.

I'd like to be able to detect if a file loads on my site that's being called from another location. The best example I can provide is the following:

I'm able to edit my computers host file to block specific domain names. If I have external.com blocked and mysite.com uses resources from external.com, those resources won't load.

So I'd like to know if there's any way I can detect weather any or all of the resources from external.com are loading when a user visits my site and if possible set up an action to redirect any users that have external.com blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't detect if something is specifically blocked - but you CAN check to see whether or not it has successfully loaded by attaching an onload event to an element:

In HTML:

```
<element onload="doSomething()" />
```

In Javascript:

```
object.onload = function(){ //Do Something };
```

In Javascript attaching an event listener:

```
object.addEventListener( 'load', doSomething() );
```

I would suggest that maybe your 'doSomething()' function could set a flag when particular resources load, then you can check those flags with another function and take whatever action you deem appropriate if anything is missing.

The only problem is - with regard to your original question - you can't assume that they're blocking resources from blah.com ... only that resources from blah.com failed to load.

Comment: No, you're right ... absolutely right.  Problem is, there is no javascript 'onLoadFailed' event.  So, you need to turn your problem upside-down.

Comment: @zero Could do a setTimeout that does your "onLoadFailed" stuff and have the onLoad event clear the timeout so that the onLoadFailed doesn't get called. (Use however long you want for the timeout)

Comment: @Terminus That's a very clever solution but Its a little messy imo and I'd much rather an instant response. However I may fallback onto that, thanks.

Comment: Definitely messy @zero and depending on how long you wait could yield false positives. If you find something more elegant, please come back and share! :D

Comment: If you are just trying to check for domain avaliability, at least you can use a 1x1px image tag with an onerror() event

Comment: @zero don't know if you checked back on your question already but marcos' onerror seems to be the answer!